# Calculate the applied force associated with uniform distortion of an area

Tags: energy, stress-strain

I am exploring Hooke's Law and considering how it might apply to an arbitrary area (perhaps as a slice of some volume).

Since $$ F = -kx $$

Would it be correct to calculate the force, $F$, associated with uniform distortion of an area as follows:

$$F = -kx^2$$

Comment: In an attempt to be more clear, allow me to state: I am considering uniform deformation over an area as a slice of some volume (dx displacement due to some applied force).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not like that. First of all, you don't represent energy by $F$. That's probably a typo. And for the calculation of energy, it is not just $E=F \times x = kx^2$ because as the $x$ changes, the force acting on that part of the object also changes. Hence the force is not uniform and we have to integrate taking differential portions in order to get the required expression.

Say we consider a portion at a distance $x$ from one side. So force acting on that portion is $F=kx$. Now for $dx$ displacement due to the stress applied, the work done = energy used = $E= kx \cdot dx$

Hence the total energy is given by summing all such $dx$ parts i.e. by integrating:
$$E=\int kx \cdot dx = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

Comment: Thanks for this clear and understandable explanation. Also for the benefit of the doubt in pointing out the type error. : ) I had a migraine when I wrote this. Actually, I was attempting to ask the question differently. Since, $F=−kx$ is (if I understand correctly) for straight line elasticity, How would I calculate $F$ over an elastic area? Like bulk modulus, I think, but as a "slice", not volume.

Comment: @LoveFineArt The relation $F=-kx$ is valid upto the elastic limit of the material of a body, after that the relation does not hold and there are quadratic terms and cubic terms introduced in the relation between stress and strain. But I coudn't understand the meaning of your question. Can you be a little more clear with actually what you mean by "calculating $F$ over an elastic area"?